Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users not working as expected
I am new to the salesforce ecosystem and was experimenting with MFA. I have enabled the Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users permission set for an user but its still enforcing the user to login with mfa. The user has only one permission set and is part of a sandbox environment. Am I doing something wrong ? It would be great if you can point me in the right direction.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Verify if you have another permission set that is requiring MFA. I experienced once two permission sets that were opposing each other which seemed to provided inconsistency in results at login.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
